# Nexus proxy repository security scan options

Tags: nexus, scanning

We have a community edition Nexus repository manager as proxy to a number of public repositories, e.g. dockerhub, quay.io, pypi, maven central etc.
This all seems to work well as proxy but we'd now like to implement additional security scans when downloading remote libraries/images. Does anyone know if Nexus has any options for this without going to the enterprise licensed version?

The main thing we'd like to prevent is for malicious libraries to be used by our teams, but I guess vulnerability scans would be good as well.

Thanks